# Eclipse error - Creating directories for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile failed

Tags: eclipse, aem

Things have been going fine in my localhost Adobe Experience Manager 6.5.3 development environment, but suddenly I'm unable to push commits. After doing some digging, I found the following in my error log (see below). I've tried various fixes, but can't figure out what it is.

I'm also getting a "Problem Occurred" error with the message below, which I think is related:

```
Publishing failed
Could not publish to the server.
unknown type: 0,date,dd.MM.yyyy\ HH:mm:ss.SSS
Failed publishing path=/conf, result=JcrResult[ success:false, exception: org.apache.sling.ide.transport.RepositoryException - javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Item is protected]
```

Has anyone run into this before and, if so, how did you fix it? Thanks.

```
eclipse.buildId=4.18.0.I20201202-1800
java.version=11.0.10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-06-05 00:14:42.561
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-06-05 00:14:42.561
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@43d2c8e3,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@8bb5c2a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 4 0 2021-06-05 00:14:56.710
!MESSAGE Cannot save config file 'FileBasedConfig[C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.config\jgit\config]'
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Creating directories for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.config\jgit failed
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.mkdirs(FileUtils.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.LockFile.lock(LockFile.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.save(FileBasedConfig.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FileStoreAttributes.saveToConfig(FS.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FileStoreAttributes.lambda$4(FS.java:424)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 4 0 2021-06-05 00:14:59.729
!MESSAGE WinHttp.GetProxyForUrl for pac failed with error 'The proxy auto-configuration script could not be downloaded
' #12167.
```

Comment: `Creating directories for C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.config\jgit failed` probably due to a lack of permissions. It seems to be related to Git. What is the environment variable `HOME` set to?

Comment: Your suggestion actually revealed something to me. I'm no longer able to access Environmental Variables and get "This app has been blocked by your system administrator. Contact your system administrator for more info." Corporate must have pushed an update to my PC that caused this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm able to access Environment Variables again. The variable "Home" is set to %userprofile%.